.htaccess Rewrite Query String as Query String
I've read a lot of questions and answers about how to rewrite a URL query string as a path, but none on how to rewrite the query string itself. I have an existing URL that will be accessed indefinitely because it was published historically and I need to rewrite both the URL and the QUERY_STRING to submit to a new folder structure. I've got the URL rewrite working just fine, but need to rewrite the QUERY_STRING portion and I even have the RewriteCond working for the string.
OLD => https://example.com/sub1/sub2/?key1=data.001&url=https://example.com/sub1/sub3/data_001/data_001_config.txt

NEW => https://example.com/alt1/sub1/sub2/?key1=data.001&url=https://example.com/alt1/alt2/sub3/data_001/data_001_config.txt

My .htaccess that is working is:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?sub1/sub2/(.*)$ /alt1/sub1/sub2/$1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=https://example.com/sub1(.*)$

RewriteRule

I just need to know what that last RewriteRule is or if there is a better way to approach it.

The RewriteRule should match the path of the old URL. And then you put your new substitution URL, and add the R and QSD flags. And you need to put this before the more generic rule that is supposed to handle the rest of URLs starting with /sub1/sub2/.
